# Enabling IPv6 on interface

Tags: networking, interface, ipv6

I have a lot of trouble enabling IPv6 on physical interface, everything seems enabled or not disabled:

$ ifconfig enp1s0

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 7c:d3:0a:10:1d:0e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2567213  bytes 1896259903 (1.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4022172  bytes 4859940550 (4.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

$ sudo sysctl -p

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

$ cat /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Webmin isn't helping either
[IPv6 always returns to disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNEYy.png),
[Even if I enable IPv6 discovery and save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTd5b.png),
[On the list loopback and Docker both show up with IPv6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy4A.png).

$ cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

$  cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

```
network:
  ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            addresses: ['192.168.0.254/24']
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 127.0.0.53]
  version: 2
```

I think I'm starting to see what needs to be done.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include which version of Ubuntu you're running? It looks like you're running Debian ...

Comment: It seems you did not configure your ipv6 interface. Please also post your netplan yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what needed to be done: I needed to add `dhcp6: yes` to the interface in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml file.

```
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: yes
```

I have added `dhcp4: no` just to be safe.

Thanks Thomas Aichinger for pointing out this file.